# Is a geodesic the least curved path?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, calculus-of-variations, curvature, geodesic

It is clear that, in $\mathbb{R}^n$, straight lines are the lines with minimum possible curvature. 
That is, given the Frenet-Serret ($n$-dimensional equivalent) matrix, and taking its squared norm, we can integrate it along the line and get zero on a straight line, and a positive number on any other curve.

Can we generalize this idea to arbitrary Riemannian manifolds? (What about any affine connection?)

In other words. Is there a variational principle on curvature, rather than on length?

Any reference is welcome.

Comment: I envision a space like an lop-sided egg. Imagine a pair of points near the pointy end. The path connecting the points which is shortest is also more curved. So, as geodesic is defined to be least distance path, I'd say your proposal may have trouble.

Comment: I see your point, and that's why I am not sure. But that is extrinsic curvature, which is not seen from the "inside". And also, the integral of the curvature along the path, if the curvature is never zero, increases with the length.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about the integration of a smaller quantity along a longer path length, that may undo my concern.

Answer (score 5):

Geodesics are in fact the paths of zero (intrinsic) curvature. The standard definition of a geodesic requires that the covariant derivative of its unit tangent vector along the curve be $0$.

Comment: Right. Then the question becomes, "Can we express this as a variational principle?"

Comment: Yes. Sure, but I don't think it's so useful. Obviously $\int \kappa\,ds$ is minimized on a path where $\kappa=0$ identically. (Recall that $\kappa\ge 0$ by definition.) Here, of course, I mean the intrinsic $\kappa$ if you're thinking of a submanifold.